# Merge raw sql in Entity framework querys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to merge raw sql conditions in an Entity Framework query?

Ex.:

```
var items = db.Posts.where(x => x.UserId == userId);
items = items.where("posts.foo = ?", bar);
return items.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you would want to do that because the context is not clear to me? Is this something you can't achieve with Linq2Sql?

Comment: @GlenThomas, this is for some reports, where end user can write some "extra" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

No in supported way. the only close way will be:

```
var items = p in posts
where p.foo == bar
select p
```